# Website appears in chinese when I search on google

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, meta-tags

My WordPress site got hacked recently and I removed the hacked files and did everything what Google requires to do to recover it, but still, when I search my website, it appears with some chinses words. Also, Used malware removal plugin, Google ownership configurations added, configurated google analytics.

After doing this "This site got hacked" label got removed but still showing some Chinese words in Google search.

[image: oo]

Comment: Try this: https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/6349986?hl=en

Comment: What happens when you click on that Chinese link to your site?  Do you get a 404 page, or do you still see Chinese content?

Comment: Google maintains a guide for fixing hacked sites: [How to Fix A Hacked Website - Google Webmasters](https://www.google.com/webmasters/hacked/?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

frstly examine your site may if your site is wordpress and your using yoast you will find the xml sitemap link in your yoast settings. make sure you have nothing in your site map you dont recognise. then in google search console check for any indexing errors once sure your site is clean request google to recrawl your site.

if you have double and triple made sure your site is clean the recrawl will fix your listing